# Converting dates in SPSS

Tags: datetime, spss

I have data from Survey Monkey and the dates that the responses were provided are transferring over in a strange format. They look like:

"1036914:34:45.00"

I have altered the variable type to every available option that SPSS provides and none of them are giving me the right data.

The number that I pasted above should be a date/time between the end of March and the beginning of April of 2018.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Nice one! could you add a couple more examples?

Answer (score 0):

This should be the number of

> "hours:minutes:seconds.centiseconds"

that have passed since 01/01/1900. I looked it up and your example would be

> Monday 16 April 2018 at 18:34:45

This is probably an MS Excel format?